# API function for get motherboard and other device information

Tags: c#, api

I have get motherboard and other device information in computer (name and serial number), for example:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)
[DllImport("user32.dll",SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool GetWindowInfo(IntPtr hwnd, ref WINDOWINFO pwi);
```

its use for GetWindowInfo, but i have get motherboard and other device information, Similar device Manager in Windows.

As well as, I use this site, But not find this API.

[enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff818516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: why don't you look up `WMI` I am pretty sure it can query most System wide stuff have you tried a google search

Comment: I search in google, msdn,... but not find answer, please help me for api function name  for this

Answer (score 0):

1. Get all `WMI` classes
   [with PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393244(v=vs.85).aspx)
2. Select needed class
3. [Querying with WQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392902(v=vs.85).aspx)